# How to set y-axis title and change the font style in UpsetR plot?

Tags: r, upsetr, upsetplot, complex-upset

I am trying to plot an intersection graph using UpSetR for an Orthogroup gene count dataset that looks like this -

[image]

I need to highlight certain intersections, the names 'Mdong', 'Mfastidious' etc, need to be in italics as they are names of bacteria and the y-axis title has to be changed to 'Number of genes shared' . I used the following code and was able to get the intersections but I don't know how to include the italics and y-axis title. I tried including ggplot2 as well but it did not work.

```
library(UpSetR)
library(ggplot2)

mydataframe <- data.frame(Orthogroup = c("OG0000000", "OG0000001", "OG0000002", "OG0000003", "OG0000004", "OG0000005", "OG0000006", "OG0000007", "OG0000008", "OG0000009", "OG0000010", "OG0000011", "OG0000012"), Mdong = c(9,3,7,0,3,0,5,3,8,14,0,4,6), Midriensis = c(6,8,9,0,6,0,5,6,6,4,0,8,9), Mcrassostreae = c(4,7,3,5,11,3,9,6,10,3,0,4,5))

selected_species <- colnames(mydataframe)[2:(ncol(mydataframe))]
```

All columns have to be integers, so -

```
mydataframe[mydataframe > 0] <- 1
```

Plot -

```
upset(mydataframe, sets = rev(selected_species), keep.order = T, order.by = "freq", queries=list(list(query = intersects, params = list("Mdong","Midriensis"), color = "red", active = T)), ylab("Number of genes shared"))
```

This seems to work well for having highlighted intersects but the 'ylab()' is ignored. I also checked [examples -R ComplexUpset by krassowski](https://krassowski.github.io/complex-upset/articles/Examples_R.html#counts) but I guess I don't know how to use UpSetR or ComplexUpset properly.
How do I include all this within a single command? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's easier to help if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example).  Worth checking out [ggupset](https://github.com/const-ae/ggupset) which offers category highlighting and integrates well with `ggplot`.

Comment: Hi @Carl. Thank you for the suggestion but I couldn't figure it out. I have edited my question with a reproducible example. Is this enough to answer my question? please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supplied code wouldn't run for me, so I'm not sure if this is what you intended. Nonetheless, it does show how to highlight the names with italics (`Mdong` in this example) and get a y-axis label. I've used ggupset because it plays nicely with ggplot.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggupset)
# to enable italics
library(ggtext)

mydataframe <-
  data.frame(
    Orthogroup = c(
      "OG0000000",
      "OG0000001",
      "OG0000002",
      "OG0000003",
      "OG0000004",
      "OG0000005",
      "OG0000006",
      "OG0000007",
      "OG0000008",
      "OG0000009",
      "OG0000010",
      "OG0000011",
      "OG0000012"
    ),
    Mdong = c(9, 3, 7, 0, 3, 0, 5, 3, 8, 14, 0, 4, 6),
    Midriensis = c(6, 8, 9, 0, 6, 0, 5, 6, 6, 4, 0, 8, 9),
    Mcrassostreae = c(4, 7, 3, 5, 11, 3, 9, 6, 10, 3, 0, 4, 5)
  )

set_df <- mydataframe |>
  pivot_longer(-Orthogroup) |> 
  distinct(value, name) |> 
  arrange(value, name) |> 
  mutate(
    # select the names to be markdown formatted, e.g. italics
    name = if_else(name %in% c("Mdong"), str_c("*", name, "*"), name),
    gene = list(name), 
    .by = value
    ) |>
  distinct(gene, value)

label_df <- set_df |> count(gene)

set_df |>
  ggplot(aes(gene)) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_label(aes(y = n, label = n), data = label_df) +
  scale_x_upset() +
  labs(
    # with y-axis label
    x = "Combinations", y = "Number of genes shared",
    title = "Most Frequent Gene Combinations"
  ) +
  # to enable italics
  theme(axis.text.y = element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-13 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>